# Using json_normalize to build table from nested values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, json-normalize

I am running into trouble using json_normalize when the record_path points to a column where there is a nested dict which then contains a list.  See below for example.

Given the following:

```
list_of_dict = [
{
    'SCHOOL_NAME': 'SCHOOL_A',
    'STUDENTS': [
        {
            'STUDENT_NAME': 'JOHN',
            'STUDENT_ID': '1'
        },
        {
            'STUDENT_NAME': 'JANE',
            'STUDENT_ID': '2'
        },
    ]
},
{
    'SCHOOL_NAME': 'SCHOOL_B',
    'STUDENTS': [
        {
            'STUDENT_NAME': 'HENRY',
            'STUDENT_ID': '1'
        },
        {
            'STUDENT_NAME': 'MARK',
            'STUDENT_ID': '2'
        },
    ]
}]
```

I can flatten this using

```
pd.json_normalize(data=list_of_dict, record_path='STUDENTS', meta=['SCHOOL_NAME'])[['SCHOOL_NAME', 'STUDENT_ID', 'STUDENT_NAME']]
```

to obtain the following:

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPr3y.png)

How can I obtain similar output format if the list_of_dict is structured as follows:
** NOTE THE ADDITION OF STUDENT_LIST **

```
list_of_dict = [
{
    'SCHOOL_NAME': 'SCHOOL_A',
    'STUDENT_LIST':{
        'STUDENTS': [
            {
                'STUDENT_NAME': 'JOHN',
                'STUDENT_ID': '1'
            },
            {
                'STUDENT_NAME': 'JANE',
                'STUDENT_ID': '2'
            },
        ]
    }

},
{
    'SCHOOL_NAME': 'SCHOOL_B',
    'STUDENT_LIST': {
        'STUDENTS': [
            {
                'STUDENT_NAME': 'HENRY',
                'STUDENT_ID': '1'
            },
            {
                'STUDENT_NAME': 'MARK',
                'STUDENT_ID': '2'
            },
        ]
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dict comprehension` with `pop`:

```
# Just pop key `STUDENT_LIST` and your list_of_dict is back like before
In [680]: a = [{**x, **x.pop('STUDENT_LIST')} for x in list_of_dict]

# Now use `json_normalize`
In [684]: pd.json_normalize(a, record_path='STUDENTS', meta=['SCHOOL_NAME'])
Out[684]: 
  STUDENT_NAME STUDENT_ID SCHOOL_NAME
0         JOHN          1    SCHOOL_A
1         JANE          2    SCHOOL_A
2        HENRY          1    SCHOOL_B
3         MARK          2    SCHOOL_B
```